# EitherT in Scala not working with For Comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, either

I have this code:

```
 (for {
      oldResult <- EitherT[Future, A, B](getById(id))
      newResult <- EitherT.right(update(changeOldData(oldResult)))
    } yield newResult).value
```

Where the functions returns

```
 getById       -> Future[Either[A, B]]
 update        -> Future[B]
 changeOldData -> B
```

The entire block is suppose to return:

```
Future[Either[A, B]]
```

In IntelliJ, there is no complains about the code above, but when compiling, I'm getting the following error:

```
[error]  found   : B => cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Nothing,B]
[error]  required: B => cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,A,B]
[error]           oldResult <- EitherT[Future, A, B](
```

I tried to not include the type and I'm getting the same error as well.
Any idea why?

Comment: It's important to note that IntelliJ's presentation compiler for Scala does not have full functionality. So never rely on int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `EitherT.right(..)` the compiler cannot figure out what the left type of your either should be. That's why the error message says it found `Nothing` instead of A. You need to help it out a bit.

```
EitherT.right[A](update(changeOldData(oldResult)))
```

This will compile.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue. The funny part is that the error related to the first part of the For and not the second one.